# ggplot shows different graph in R console vs after knitting

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, knitr

[image]

Refer to the picture, somehow all the graphs in that code chunk have rendered differently in HTML. Other code chunks also had ggplot graphs that rendered fine?! not sure what would be the reason for this discrepancy. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On the left graph the year_id is a factor or character.

Would have to see the rest of the code to determine why.

Something further up probably changes it or defines it differently.

Comment: Yes, I converted the year_id to factor cause I wanted the plots to look that way(like on the left). I removed the conversion to factor and now both the plots look similar(like on the right) but that's not what I want :(

Comment: Again, we would need to see all of the Rmd to pinpoint why it does this, or doesn't do this, but just use x = as.factor( year_id ) in the aesthetics if you don't want to find out why

Comment: So, i looked at the RMD properly this time and realized I had factored some of the year-id fields but not all and hence the plots looked different, changed that as per your last comment and now its all good. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Great! had to be something, glad to help